# Unzipping without first directory in java

Tags: java, zip

I would like a zip file Test.zip containing 2 folders, say, A and B, to be unzipped outside of Test folder.
For now A and B are unzipped within Test folder i.e Test->A and Test->B, whereas I want it in a different folder like Test2->A and Test2->B. right now I am getting an output like Test2->Test->A.
How can i achieve this? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like your `Test.zip` file simply contains a folder named "Test" that in turn contains A and B. Could you verify if this is the case?

If that's so, maybe you could detect if the zip file contains a single directory with the same name as the file. If that is so, extract from that subdirectory into your target. If not, extract directly from the zip root.

Comment: Oh, yes. that was the problem. It did have a folder named Test. Thanks a million.

Comment: Isn't it always fun when you unzip some file to your desktop, assuming it's gonna contain a folder and then there's suddenly a million files all over the place? :D

Comment: Absolutely :) I was totally lost till now.